# Where can one report bad experience with a landlord/place to stay?

Tags: online-resources, legal, accommodation, security, rental

Is there an online web service where people can report other people of bad landlords/places to stay? It might not be directly connected to fast traveling (in my case at least), but rather something like 2+ months. Although I imagine the same web service could be used in both cases..

So, if you're staying somewhere for example 2 months and if you had bad enough experience is there a place where you could warn other people by saying "look, don't go there, they were bad because of xy"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a rented out house like on [Airbnb.com](http://airbnb.com) or a homestay of some sort, then you could leave a review on [Tripadvisor](http://tripadvisor.com). Otherwise, this question is something that falls outside the scope of what travellers have to face. Renting a place typically requires some kind of security deposit, contracts, et al that is not the concern of travellers.

Comment: I agree, you can always report your stays if they are listed in hostel guide websites by writing a bad review. Don't forget to write exact reasons why you think others wouldn't enjoy the stay at that certain place. I agree with Ankur Banerjee that this site is mainly for people traveling and not for those that stay somewhere long enough to rent a place long term (although there are some that do that as well).

Comment: For **hostels**, what review site would you guys recommend? I've usually used http://hostelworld.com to determine if a place is good or not. But if I recall correctly, it has a big limitation: you can only leave a review if you booked your stay through that site.

Answer (score 3):

To review anything, I am using either foursquare or places.google.com